# Include a JavaScript containing Php in WordPress

Tags: javascript, php, json, wordpress

I'm currently working on an interactive map (using OpenStreetMap and OpenLayers), which works as I want on a local website (see this screenshot : https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ev08B.jpg).

My code uses Html, Php and JavaScript.

I wish to integrate this interactive map into a page of my WordPress website. For the Php part, it's simple, I use the shortcode technique. I already tested it, it works, including the communication with the database.

However, the map itself is a JavaScript script. I would love to use the "enqueue_script" technique, but the problem is that my script contains some Php, used to pass a json array containing basically the info to place the markers on the map.

The question is : is that possible to include this script on a WordPress page (the same as the one where I include the Php), and if so, how could I do that ?

Here is the (simplified) Php code. It works, but it might help you guys to understand what I want to do :

```
function register_shortcodes(){
    add_shortcode('fidu-display-map', 'display_map');
}
add_action( 'init', 'register_shortcodes');

function display_map(){

    generate_html();
    get_search_results();
    generate_map();
}

function generate_html(){

    echo "<div id=\"basicMap\" style=\"width: 100%;
            height: 100%; coordinates
            margin: 0;\"></div>";
}

function get_search_results(){

    global $wpdb;
    global $result;

    $result = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM search_results;", ARRAY_A);
}

function generate_map(){
    global $result;
    $res_lon = array();
    //[... other declarations]
    $res_link = array();
    foreach ($result as $row) {
        array_push($res_lon, $row['lon']);
        //[... other pushs]
        array_push($res_link, $row['societyLink']);
    }
    $search_result = array(
        $res_lon,
        //[... other merging]
        $res_link
    );
}
```

Now here is the JavaScript, with the Json part that causes me some problems because it depends on the Php above :

```
<script>

    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function()
    {
        init();
    }, false);

    var map;

    function init(){
        map = new OpenLayers.Map('basicMap');

        var mapnik = new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM();
        var fromProjection = new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326");   // Transform from WGS 1984
        var toProjection   = new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:900913"); // to Spherical Mercator Projection
        var centerPosition = new OpenLayers.LonLat(-85.00,38.00).transform( fromProjection, toProjection);
        var zoom           = 5;

        map.addLayer(mapnik);

        map.setCenter(centerPosition, zoom);


        addPoints(map);
    }

    function addPoints(map){
        var fromProjection = new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326");   // Transform from WGS 1984
        var toProjection   = new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:900913"); // to Spherical Mercator Projection
        //get positions from the search result from the database
        var positions = <?php echo json_encode($search_result) ?>;
        var infos = <?php echo json_encode($search_result) ?>;

        var coordinates = new Array();
        var pointStyle = {  externalGraphic: 'images/marker-blue.png',
            graphicWidth: 21,
            graphicHeight: 25,
            graphicYOffset: -24};

        // Layer
        var pointsLayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("Points Layer");


        // Add points to the layer
        for(i=0;i<positions[0].length;i++){
            //coordinates.push(new OpenLayers.Geometry.Point(positions[0][i], positions[1][i]).transform(fromProjection, toProjection));
            var pointFeature = new OpenLayers.Feature.Vector(
                new OpenLayers.Geometry.Point(positions[0][i], positions[1][i]).transform(fromProjection, toProjection),
                {description : infos[2][i]+'<br>'+infos[3][i]+'<br>'+infos[4][i]+' - '+infos[5][i]+'<br>'+infos[6][i]+'<br>Link: <a href="'+infos[7][i]+'">'+infos[7][i]+'</a>'},
                pointStyle
            );
            pointsLayer.addFeatures(pointFeature);
        }

        map.addLayer(pointsLayer);

        //Add a selector control to the vectorLayer with popup functions
        var controls = {
            selector: new OpenLayers.Control.SelectFeature(pointsLayer, { onSelect: createPopup, onUnselect: destroyPopup })
        };

        map.addControl(controls['selector']);
        controls['selector'].activate();
    }

    function createPopup(feature) {
        feature.popup = new OpenLayers.Popup.FramedCloud("pop",
            feature.geometry.getBounds().getCenterLonLat(),
            null,
            '<div class="markerContent">'+feature.attributes.description+'</div>',
            null,
            true,
            function() { controls['selector'].unselectAll(); }
        );
        map.addPopup(feature.popup);
    }

    function destroyPopup(feature) {
        feature.popup.destroy();
        feature.popup = null;
    }

</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do, is place those variables out of your javascript function. So for example you can put it in the `<head>` like:

```
var mapPoints = {
    positions: <?php echo json_encode($search_result) ?>,
    infos: <?php echo json_encode($search_result) ?>
}
```

Now, if you create a javascript file and use enqueue_scripts to add it to your page, you can still access `mapPoints` in your functions.

Comment: I'm not sure to understand... If I put these variables in the <head>, I have the same problem because I cannot give them to WordPress like that, can I ?

Comment: You can't combine php and javascript in a .js file. However, you can put those variables in the head (yes, you cannot use enqueue_scripts for this), but this way, all of the other parts of your javascript can go into a simple .js file and you can use enqueue_scripts to add it to your page. This is good, because the actual logic is in a separated javascript file, and the variables in the head are the "bridge" between your php and javascript code, and only that is extracted into the head.

Comment: Ok I understand now, thanks for this answer. However, I'm integrating this in WordPress, which means the header is already done. My shortcode is going in a <div> dedicated to the content. Do you think I could put those variables into a <div> as well ?

Comment: If those variables are above of the actual javascript file which uses enqueue_scripts, then they will be available the same way as if they were in the head.

Comment: That was more complicated than I expected (because there were other problems in my code), but now I managed to get everything to work. THe solution to this specific question is exactly what you told. Thanks a lot for your help !